# How to temporarily switch from ssh to my local shell?

Tags: command-line, ssh

I'm using cygwin. and use it with ssh to login into a ubuntu server. sometimes, I want to switch back to my cygwin and then quickly switch to ubuntu shell. How to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can background the ssh client just like any other shell job by sending it a signal and returning to the parent shell. Since the ssh client traps most key strokes, it would grab the normal shell job control keystrokes, but you can get its attention and get through to the shell using an escape sequence. For most ssh-clients this involves sending a `~` that has been directly preceded by a newline. The following sequence should do the job:

<kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>~</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

After it is suspended you can continue using the local shell. When you want to go back to the suspended job, just run the `fg` command.

For further reading, look up [Bash Job Control](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_5.html).

Comment: Nice; beat me to it.  For more further reading, run `man ssh` and search for "Escape Characters", or type `~?` in an ssh session.

Comment: ...and if your ssh session is your top level session, remember not to use it next time! (a lot of my ssh sessions are auto-started from iTerm).

Answer (score 2):

@Caleb's answer is good, but you could also consider installing a terminal multiplexer like `screen` or `tmux`. Apparently (according to what I can find on the web) `tmux` has had some problems with running on Cygwin in the past, but I don't know about the current status of it.

Comment: Both `tmux` and `screen` can certainly be used to solve the problem the OP is facing, but getting started with a multiplexer is quite pile of stuff to get your head around the first time. Perhaps you could expand this answer to an exact set of commands for `tmux` that would get a newcomer through the process of opening a terminal, ssh'ing, detatching back to the main shell, then attaching again...